# Por que que esse algoritmo pula os if?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumPri {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner le = new Scanner(System.in);

        String produto, nome, resp;
        double desconto, acrecimo, preco, novoPreco = 0;

        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("                      LOJA DE 1,99");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Qual o seu nome meu chapa: ");
        nome = le.nextLine();

        System.out.print(nome + ", qual o nome do produto que quer comprar: ");
        produto = le.nextLine();

        System.out.print(nome + ", qual o preço normal de 1 " + produto + ": ");
        preco = le.nextDouble();

        System.out.print(nome + ", você quer dar um desconto >des< ou um acrécimo >aum< no valor total do seu produto? > ");
        resp = le.nextLine();

        System.out.println();

        if (resp == "des") {
            System.out.print("e ai meu chapa, de quantos por cento irá ser o seu desconto: ");
            desconto = le.nextDouble();
            novoPreco = preco - (preco * desconto / 100);
        }

        if (resp == "aum") {
            System.out.print("e ai meu chapa, de quantos por cento vai ser o seu aumento: ");
            acrecimo = le.nextDouble();
            novoPreco = preco + (preco * acrecimo / 100);

        }

        System.out.println(nome + ", o " + produto + " que valia R$" + preco + " agora vale: R$" + novoPreco);

    }
}
```

***Saída do console:***

> ----------------LOJA DE 1,99 ----------------
>
> Qual o seu nome meu chapa: lucas lucas, qual o nome do produto que
> quer comprar: nescal lucas, qual o preço normal de 1 nescal: 10,0
> lucas, você quer dar um desconto >des< ou um acrécimo >aum< no valor
> total do seu produto? > lucas, o nescal que valia R$10.0 agora vale:
> R$0.0, acima é oq o console faz.

Comment: `if (resp == "des")` e `if (resp == "aum")` - Basicamente, nunca compare strings com o `==` ou com o `!=`. Use o método `equals` tal como explicado na questão que marquei como duplicata.